# Issue in setting container's height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm newbie in flutter.i have a code to set height of the container.
here please check, if the condition gets true its sets height 100 else 60,i want to set the 60 as its child's height.means it should have to

selectedIndex != null && showExpanded == true
                        ? 100
                        : (depends upon child's height),

here is my code...

```
                    height: selectedIndex != null && showExpanded == true
                        ? 100
                        : 60,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    // Provide an optional curve to make the animation feel smoother.
                    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border:
                            Border.all(width: 1, color: HexColor("#BCE0FD"))),)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to container match its height with its child just set its height field to null.

```
height: selectedIndex != null && showExpanded == true
      ? 100
      : null,
```